# Pythonic and secure way to convert a list of integers to a string and vis-à-vis

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `list` of integers (e. g. `[1, 2, 3]` and want to convert them to one string (e. g. `"1, 2, 3"`). Later I will convert the string back into a list of integers.

Is my solution pythonic enough or is there a much easier way?

```
# init values
int_list = [1, 2, 3]

# list of integers to string
string = str(int_list)[1:-1]

# string to list of integers
int_list = [int(i) for i in string.split(',')]
```

By the way: My first approach was to do `exec("int_list = [" + str + "]"`). But using `exec` is absolutly not recommended.

Comment: What are you going to do with this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = list(map(str, a))
c = list(map(int, b))
```

EDIT: if you want only one string, then

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ",".join(map(str, a))
c = list(map(int, b.split(",")))
```

EDIT2: you can also use [this](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448) to convert the map to a list. I don't like it too much, but it's an option:

```
c = [*map(int, b.split(","))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# to string
a = [1,2,3]
s = repr(a)
print(s)

# from string
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval(s))
```

Unlike `eval`, [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) "can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself."